# Looking for awk command to append filename at end of line

Tags: regex, ubuntu, text, awk

I have a text file with filenames that I would like to be dynamically appended to the end of each line.  For example, I would like the following:

```
/home/danrothaudiodsp/kaldi-trunk/egs/voxforge/s5/voxforge/extracted/1028-20100710-hne/wav/ar-01.wav 

/home/danrothaudiodsp/kaldi-trunk/egs/voxforge/s5/voxforge/extracted/1028-20100710-hne/wav/ar-02.wav
```

to become:

```
/home/danrothaudiodsp/kaldi-trunk/egs/voxforge/s5/voxforge/extracted/1028-20100710-hne/wav/ar-01.wav /home/danrothaudiodsp/gfcc_train/ar-01.gfcc

/home/danrothaudiodsp/kaldi-trunk/egs/voxforge/s5/voxforge/extracted/1028-20100710-hne/wav/ar-02.wav /home/danrothaudiodsp/gfcc_train/ar-02.gfcc
```

This needs to iterate over a large text file with many lines like this.

I already have the following awk command:

```
awk '{$2="/home/danrothaudiodsp/gfcc_train/" OFS $2} 1' file > newfile
```

but I am looking for the value to fill in after the last '/' that follows gfcc_train.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{fname=$0; sub(/.*\//,"",fname); sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",fname); print $0, "/home/danrothaudiodsp/gfcc_train/" fname ".gfcc"}' file
/home/danrothaudiodsp/kaldi-trunk/egs/voxforge/s5/voxforge/extracted/1028-20100710-hne/wav/ar-01.wav /home/danrothaudiodsp/gfcc_train/ar-01.gfcc
/home/danrothaudiodsp/kaldi-trunk/egs/voxforge/s5/voxforge/extracted/1028-20100710-hne/wav/ar-02.wav /home/danrothaudiodsp/gfcc_train/ar-02.gfcc
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
((\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+).+\/(.+)\.wav)
```

might be helpful to look into and translate it to `awk`.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/0teWyu/1/)

Comment: The problem with those online regexp tools is they don't adequately take into account the command-line tool you want to use the regexp in so they almost always validate some regexp that simply will not work in the target tool and often the target tool has a simpler (or more robust or otherwise better) way to accomplish the task anyway. So using an online tool to learn about regexps in general is fine but using one to generate/validate a regexp to use in any given command line tool is practically useless.